# Stored procedure execution time went from under 2mins to "infinity" without modifications

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, stored-procedures, optimization

I have an SSRS report that pulls it's source from a vendor's MSSQL 2012 database. It's an extensive dataset so I've created a stored procedure that runs at the same time every morning.

There's quite a bit happening in that stored proc, but I had optimized it to run in about a minute and a half. It did so for the last 3 months without any issues until this morning. When I came in and checked the logs, I saw that the sp was still running (2 hours later). I waited a bit, then stopped it thinking it might just be hanging.

I tried executing it again and it's been running for over an hour again.

The only thing I can think of that changed was an update that the vendor applied to the database yesterday.

I tried to run a query to see if there were any locks on the tables that I'm pulling data from, but I don't have sufficient permissions. I also ran `sp_who2` to get some info as I read on here that it might help out, but all I've learnt is the following:

`Status = RUNNABLE` | `BlkBy = .` | `Command = SELECT INTO` | `CPUTime = 47` | `DiskIO = 0`

I'll be contacting the database administrator to troubleshoot, but I'd like to get an idea of what I can suggest, since the hourly rate for support services is very expensive and they often try to extend the call beyond what is necessary.

Is there something to look at right away when a stored procedure suddenly becomes inefficient overnight?

Comment: is the update updating all rows ? how big is the table ? What was the query waiting for - waitstats ? We would need a query plan (actual plan xml - use pastebin and link it here).

Comment: @Kin It isn't updating any records. Instead it's deleting all the records in the table for the current fiscal year and repopulating the aggregated data for that fiscal year in the stored procedure. The table has less than 60,000 records. I'm not sure what the query was waiting for, how do I identify that? I am running the execution plan currently.

Comment: There are a number of things that could affect the execution time. Is regular maintenance being run on the indexes? Does the stored procedure accept input values? If so, do the input values change? If the values do change it could be that the execution plan was created based on "bad" variables. Have the table(s) increased in row count? I also agree with @Kin that you may also need to look at waitstats. Alternatively to using pastebin you can upload the execution plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: @Adam I believe they have a maintenance schedule for the indexes. The stored procedure accepts an input value, but is optional (if no value is provided, the current fiscal year is assumed). The value would have been the same for the last 3 months. The tables that I'm pulling from (the vendor tables) increase in records every night. I will look into the waitstats.

Comment: `(the vendor tables) increase in records every night.` this means that the stats will be outdated thereby producing bad plan. Either update stats after the load or use `option (recompile)` query hint.

Comment: @Kin The execution plan has taken nearly an hour and I `SET FMTONLY ON`. I therefore cancelled it. Tried updating stats with `sp_updatestats` but I don't have sufficient permissions for that either. So I've set it to recompile and that's been running for over 7 minutes now.

Comment: @JTT if you aren't able to get the actual execution plan you could provide the estimated plan.

Comment: Just covering the bases here, but have you checked to make sure there aren't any other transactions open that could be blocking this report?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions. I've updated with the solution reply from the DBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a follow-up from the database administrator. So I will post his message as the answer.

I tried again after receiving his message and sure enough the stored procedure ran in under 2 minutes.

His email:

> Seems that the issue was a deadlock on the db. I killed the locked processes and it seems fine now.
>
> The system update essentially caused rehashing in some of the tables and the replication job to your datamart hung up because of this.
>
> Please try again and let me know.

---

**Edit**: Additional Information

If you have the same issue, please also consider the comment from @Kin below since I am unable to confirm 100% that the DBA actually did what he said.

@Kin: Well, SQL Server will automatically choose the deadlock victim based on the log usage (the process using less log will be killed unless you have deadlock priority set). I think, it is a blocking issue not a deadlock as thats where you kill the offending process.

Comment: Well, SQL Server will automatically choose the deadlock victim based on the log usage (the process using less log will be killed unless you have deadlock priority set). I think, it is a blocking issue not a deadlock as thats where you **kill the offending process**.

Comment: I hope you don't mind. I've added your comment to the answer in case it helps someone. Thanks for the info.